# SwiftのArrayをNSArrayと同様に参照渡しで使えますか？

Tags: swift

お世話になります。

SwiftのArrayは値渡し、NSMutableArrayは参照渡しと聞きました。

SwiftのArrayでも、NSMutableArrayのように参照渡しで使用することはできないのでしょうか？

値渡しですと、Arrayの要素を変更した後に、再度Arrayに代入しなおすいうことが必要になると思います。
その点では、NSMutableArrayの方が使いやすいと思うのですが。
SwiftのArrayでも同様のことができますか？

ご教示お願いいたします。

Comment: 「SwiftのArrayは値渡し、NSMutableArrayは参照渡し」は正しくなく、「SwiftのArrayは値型、NSMutableArrayは参照型」になります。評価戦術としては値渡し、参照渡しのいずれも可能です。ここで仰っている「参照渡し」は実際には「共有渡し（参照値の値渡し）」が近いニュアンスだと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swiftには値型と参照型があります。参照型を使ってデータを管理すれば、ArrayをNSMutableArrayと同じように使えます。

Xcode 7.1.1のPlaygroundで確認。

```
import Foundation

/// 参照型でデータを管理
class RefType : CustomStringConvertible {
    var no = 0
    var name = "name"

    init(no: Int, name: String) {
        self.no = no
        self.name = name
    }

    var description: String {
        return "no:\(no) name: \(name)"
    }
}

func testRefType() {

    // 参照型の配列を作成
    var ar = [RefType]()

    let t0 = RefType(no: 1, name: "one")
    ar.append(t0)

    let t1 = RefType(no: 2, name: "two")
    ar.append(t1)

    print("ref array: [\(ar[0]), \(ar[1])]")

    // 参照型なので、データの変更で参照先の値が変わる
    let t3 = ar[0]
    t3.no = 3
    t3.name = "three"

    print("ref array: [\(ar[0]), \(ar[1])]")
}

testRefType()
```

実行結果。

```
ref array: [no:1 name: one, no:2 name: two]
ref array: [no:3 name: three, no:2 name: two]
```

値型と参照型について、詳細はこの辺りを参考にしてください。

The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.1): Classes and Structures  
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html

Value and Reference Types - Swift Blog - Apple Developer  
https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。CustomStringConvertibleとすることで参照型となっているということなのでしょうか？

Comment: CustomStringConvertibleはprint()で値を表示するために使っているprotocolです。値型と参照型について、簡単に言うとclassが参照型でそれ以外が値型です。細かい違いについては、回答に参考URLを追加したのでそちらを見てください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考にさせてもらいます。

Comment: 他の関数にSwiftのArrayを渡した場合、管理している要素が参照型であったとしても、要素数の変更など配列の参照そのものが変わる場合には、呼び出し元で再代入を行う必要があり、NSMutableArrayと同じ動作にはならないのではないでしょうか。

Comment: そうですね。自分の回答はArrayにデータを保存／変更する時の話だけになってます。Arrayそのものを使うときのNSMutableArrayとの違いは、kishikawa katsumiさんの回答などを参考にしてください。

Answer (score 0):

`inout`パラメータを使うと、例えば下記のような関数を定義して、

```
func add(inout stringArray: [String]) {
    stringArray.append("FooBar")
}
```

参照渡しのように利用できます。

```
var array = ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz"]

add(&array)
print(array) // => ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz", "FooBar"]
```

ただ、Arrayが値型で不変であることでプログラムがシンプルになるなどメリットがあるので、わざわざArrayを共有するような使い方はあまりしません。
（もちろんケースバイケースで状態を共有する方が良い場合もあります。が、基本的にSwiftは標準ライブラリもほとんど値型が使われていて、値型の性質をうまく利用する方がSwiftらしいコードが書けます。）